# Export all org-mode sections as Beamer frames?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

Is there a way to have *all* of my Org-mode sections export as Beamer frames? For instance, if I have a document like

```
* A
** B
** C
```

then I would like a slide for each of `A`, `B`, and `C`. Setting `H:2` gives me slides for the latter two, and `H:1` gives me a single slide for all three. I've tried setting `BEAMER_env: frame` on every single heading, but org-mode complains: 'Wrong block type at a headline named "B"'. Is there another way of achieving this slide structure?

Comment: I don't understand: what do you want the slide for A to show? Do you want it to include the entire slides for B and C? Or just the body text in A? If it's just the body text, why aren't A, B and C at the same level in the hierarchy?

Comment: I had a similar problem and in my case [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36838/19794) helped.

@Omar: In my case there would be text after the headline `A` and then `B` and `C` would have their own content. And from an `org-mode` point of view it would make sense to structure them like this (e.g. first some general remarks, then some more detailed things specialized in `B` and `C`)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem as you have had (resulting in the same error message).  There may be another better way to resolve, but not having found it, I did find that adding a heading after and for each `BEAMER_env:` frame with an `BEAMER_env: ignoreheading` -- seemed a viable work-around the problem.  The ignored heading may have any name, and is not exported, so it may work for you, too.

Comment: Your answer is a bit hard to read, so might be better supplied with an example!