# Org mode: How can I add a section-name only frame to beamer slides?

Tags: org-mode, beamer

I currently have:

```
#+options: H:2
```

and...

```
* Introduction
** Some definition
    + list item1
    + list item2
```

So I get `Introduction` section in the Outline, and a frame for `Some definition`and those two list items in it. In addition, I want a frame containing just `Introduction` title, is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to add the following code at the beginning of your org file:#+BEAMER_HEADER: \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}<beamer>\frametitle{Presentat‌​ion agenda}\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{frame}}

Comment: It worked thanks. Add this as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add the following code at the beginning of your org file:

```
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}<beamer>\frametitle{Presentat‌​‌​ion agenda}\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{frame}}
```

it will generate a toc frame at the beginning of each section, highlighting the upcoming section. You can change the title of the frame (`Presentat‌​‌​ion agenda` in the above code) at your convenience.

If you want to have a slide with the section name only (not the whole toc) then you can use:

```
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}<beamer>\frametitle{Presentat‌​‌​ion agenda} \secname \end{frame}}
```

and customize it as you wish.

Comment: This is nice but is not exactily what was asked.  Any idea how to insert a "title frame" at each section instead of a toc frame?

Comment: @JeanPierre May be you could try to tweak the proposed answer by using the \secname variable (name of current section) instead of \tableofcontents[currentsection]. I did not try this so could you leave a comment if it works ?

Comment: @JeanPierre I just tried to substitute tableofcontents[currentsection] with \secname and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Indeed, thanks!

Comment: @JeanPierre Thanks, I added this alternative to the solution